# "My breakfast is milk, bread and sausages." - Is this correct even though the second part is plural?

Tags: sentence-construction, subject-verb-agreement

> My breakfast is milk,bread and sausages.

"My breakfast" is a singular noun, but "milk,bread, and sausages" are plural noun phrase.

Is this sentence right?

Comment: What about this: "my breakfast is composed of milk, bread, and suchlike."

Comment: @Hakan  I think your sentence mentioned above is correct.But I want to know whether the native speaker express it in this way.

Comment: yep, I understand, I also wait the true about it :)

Comment: Well actually a native would either say "My breakfast consists of milk, bread and sausages." or "I (usually) have milk, bread and sausages for breakfast. Grammatically though, your sentence is correct, but I doubt  a native would use it.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, it is.

Here's why:

- **"is"** is a form of **"be"**

  > <sub>[From Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/is#is)</sub>
  >
  > third person singular present of be.
- **"be"** can mean **"composed of"**

  > <sub>[From Oxford Dictionary; sense 3.5](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/be#be)</sub>
  >
  > Consist of; constitute:
- Therefore we can say that:

  > My breakfast **is** milk, bread, and sausages.

  Simply means:

  > My breakfast **consists of** milk, bread, and sausages.

Comment: helix, your way of explaining things is tangy ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, simply think for yourself: **which word(s) is/are the subject of the sentence?**

The verb is conjugated according to the subject. In this case, `my breakfast` is the subject, so the sentence is indeed correct. In fact, all of the following are correct.

> My breakfast is milk, bread and sausages.
>
> My breakfasts are milk, bread and sausages.

Even the following is correct, with `Milk, bread and sausages` being the subject. However, this sentence sounds strange, so you will not hear it very often:

> Milk, bread and sausages are my breakfast.